# Can we say that $x=0$ is a minimum of the function $f(x)=|x|$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

The derivative of a function $f(x)$ is said to exist at $x=x_0$ if both the left-derivative $Lf^\prime(x)$ and the right-derivative $Rf^\prime(x)$ exists and they are equal i.e. $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}.$$ However, if either of them is nonexistant or not equal to each other, the function does not have a unique derivative at $x=x_0$. The derivative is said to not exists at $x=x_0$.

For example, $f(x)=|x|$ does not have a unique derivative at $x=0$ because the left-derivative and right-derivative are unequal. In this case, can we say that $x=0$ is a minimum of the function $f(x)=|x|$? Looks like the criterion of determining maximum or minimum is in trouble. Sorry for my sloppy mathematics language.

Comment: no, you cannot say that, that's not enough information. But still you can prove that your function has indeed an local (in fact a global) minimum at $x=0$

Comment: Extrema can be found at critical points of the function.  This happens at corners and cusps (where the derivative would be undefined), as well as when the derivative is equal to $0$.

Comment: You can still use the values of the lateral derivatives, even if they are not equal. Note that the derivative from the left is negative (less than or equal to a negative number, in this case $-1$) and the derivative from the right is positive (greater than or equal to a positive number, in this case $1$). This tells you that all values at points close from the left of $x=0$ are larger than the value at $x=0$ and so are the values at points close to $x=0$ from the right. Even if the derivative doesn't exist, the set of limit values of the quotient of increments can give enough information ...

Comment: ... to carry out an optimization. People in optimization call them generalized derivatives. See, for example [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) in convex optimization. The function $f(x)=|x|$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes calculus classes skip over the important step of defining what a minimum is:

> A minimum of a function $f$ is some $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $y$ in the domain.

One can also define a *local* minimum as:

> A local minimum of a function $f$ is some $x$ in the domain such that, for some $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

Notice that there are no derivatives involved here - you could take something nasty like the Weierstrass function, which isn't differentiable anywhere, and talk about the minimum value it obtains.

It's a *theorem* that if a function $f$ is differentiable (from both sides) at $x$, then $x$ can only be a local minimum (or maximum) if $f'(x)=0$ - and the proof is easy: if $f'(x) < 0$, you can see that $f(x+\alpha)$ has to be less than $f(x)$ for some small $\alpha$ due to the definition of the derivative. Likewise, if $f'(x) > 0$, one has that $f(x-\alpha)$ has to be less than $f(x)$. Either way, $f(x)$ cannot have been a local minimum. Sometimes you'll see this stated as saying that local minima/maxima may only occur at zeros of a functions derivative, points where the function is not differentiable, and endpoints  of the domain.

Basically, all we can conclude from this theorem is that for $f(x)=|x|$ the only possible location for a minimum is at $x=0$. We would have to argue by other methods why this really is a minimum - but that's easy for this example because $f(0)=0$ and $0\leq f(y)$ for every $y$ since $|y|$ is always non-negative by definition.

Comment: So a similar test should also apply to find a local maximum. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

The derivative is just a tool that's sometimes useful when looking for a minimum. In this case it's irrelevant. You know $|x| \ge 0$ for all $x$ and that the value is $0$ only when $x=0$ so that't the minimum value.

Answer (score 2):

A function does not need to be differentiable to have a minimum.

For example, the Weierstrass function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function
is differentiable nowhere but has many local minima.

In general, $x^*$ is a local minimiser of $f$ is there is some interval $I$ with $x^*$
in its interior such that $f(x) \ge f(x^*)$ for all $x \in I$.

If in addition the function is differentiable at $x=0$ then we must have $f'(x^*) = 0$.

The function $x \mapsto |x|$ is convex and there is a generalised concept of
derivative for convex functions called the subdifferential. In a similar manner to
differentiable functions, if $x^*$ is a minimiser of a convex function $f$ then we
have $0 \in \partial f(x^*)$.

In the case of the absolute value function, we have 
$\partial f(x) = \begin{cases} \{-1\},& x<0 \\
[-1,1],& x = 0 \\
\{1\},& x>0
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

The places in a function to check for minimas are:

1. Where the derivative is 0
2. Where the function is discontinuous
3. Where the derivative does not exist
4. At the edges of the valid domain (note that on a continuous function, the "edge" is infinity)

Here is a function where the global minima occurs for case #3.

Comment: Minimums or minima. Take your pick :-).

Answer (score 0):

The global minimum is the lowest value achieved by the function in its whole domain. For $|x|$, it is indisputably $0$, because $|x|\ge0$ and $|0|=0$.

For a differentiable function in an interval, the global minimum is achieved either at an endpoint of the interval or at a stationary point.

For a piecewise differentiable function, you need to consider all subintervals (here, $(-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty)$).

---

In a case like

$$\frac{x^2}{|x|},$$

all values are strictly positive and zero is never reached, but we can go as close as you want, hence we have an infimum.